# Can I dynamically define which block to override in a child template?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a base file with many {% block <name> %} tags, and a child template that I want to edit a specific block depending on a variable. I found that this was attempted and rolled back due to incompatibility, but I'm looking for a similar solution as I really like having a readable base file as opposed to dozens of if and include statements.

My initial attempt was to simply pass a variable to the block tag, `{% block domain_var %}` hoping it would parse the variable and become eg. `{% block google %}` and override the correct block, but I found that blocks are handled upstream of variables/execution.

I next tried to use `{% macro set_block(domainVar) %} {% block domainVar %} {% endmacro %}` but found it's "expecting `{% endblock %}`" first, so not a viable solution.

I'm using ansible as well, and considering trying to somehow dynamically  create the child templates. Maybe using something like `{% raw %}{% block {% endraw %}domain_var{% raw %} %} ... {% endblock%} {% endraw %}` ? It feels very forced but I'm not sure if there is any better way. I'm not wed to blocks and inheritance but I would really like to keep the base.jinja as readable as possible. (maybe there is an include & replace tag I can use in base.jinja instead of block?)